# Putty installation error on Mac

Tags: mac, terminal, putty, port, macos-mojave

(putty:46267): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:19:11.146: cannot open display: i was trying to install putty in mac majavo 10.14.4 but facing with the above error. I have followed all the steps:

1. Install Xcode.
2. Install Command Line Tools From Apple Account.
3. Launch the terminal, found in /Applications/ Utilities, type this command: Xcode-select –install.
4. Download and install Quartz.
5. Download and install MacPorts.
6. sudo port -v selfupdate.
7. Type this command sudo port install putty.

Could someone assist further.

Answer (score 1):

Installing XQuartz is sufficient to run PUTTY on MacOS. Once XQuartz is installed, launch the application. Right-click on the X icon and go to “Applications” and select “terminal”. Once you open terminal, you can launch the putty application by just “putty” command. Tried and Tested this.